# What effect causes stars to be optically enlarged at the Einstein ring of a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, simulations, gravitational-lensing

Sadly i do not know what this effect is called, but it can be seen in some simulations;

[image]

Credit to [Alessandro Roussel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8GtAXFKCM-k&ab_channel=AlessandroRoussel)

The same effect can be seen on the Wiki page for black holes.

For a while now, me and a friend have been working on a black hole renderer and atm we get results like these;

[image]

[image]

Our goal is to be as accurate as possible, within our limitations. So no MHDs, but for the disk and jet we tried to approximate what simulations look like. And before anyone says it, the receding part of the jet being visible and Blueshifted is accurate. Light rays which pass underneath the BH get deflected "upwards" into the jet which is moving down. So from their perspective the jet is approaching them, so it is Blueshifted. Also note that both of these renders have the camera (which is not stationary) move at pretty high velocities. So the doppler shift induced by that motion partially overcomes that of the disk and jet. Also note that these renders are a bit deceptive, we use Planck´s law directly to compute the colors and intensity. So the disk is *bright*. These renders show the disk at an exposure of $\frac{1}{5\times10^{15}}$. So while the receding jet may look about as bright as the approaching one, *it isnt*.

Regardless it occurred to us that, at high enough camera velocities, stars would presumably be Blueshifted enough to become visible. While researching this we noticed that the stars would also get enlarged, apparently. But we have not really been able to understand *why* this happens or how it is implemented computationally. Let alone why the stars should remain circular.

The main question is what this effect is called and why it happens ? If anyone can point us towards an implementation or at least conceptual approach as to how this is done, it would also be great. But even just a physical justification would be enough.

If it matters, we draw the black hole by tracing null geodesics in the kerr spacetime backwards, starting from the camera focal point and ending at either the celestial sphere of event horizon. To get the rays, we generate them at the cameras rest frame, transform them into the local ZAMO frame. Then we transform from the ZAMO into the global frame, in which the geodesics are solved.

Comment: The effect is called gravitational lensing. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens

Comment: So, no MHDs for your BH ZAMOs, OK,HAND.

Answer (score 0):

The effect that that causes the Einstien ring is the light falling towards the massive object as it passes, causing it to bend like the light through a lense. For that reason, it is called gravitatioinal lensing. But with a lense, it is caused by the light going slower when it enters the dense glass at an angle, causing the light waves to change course as one part of the wave front enters and slows down first. Then, as it leaves the glass, the bit that slowed down last, speeds up first (the outside for a convex lense), bending it further.